# Parse XML with TBXML into Array iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml

I have XML string look like this:

```
result = { 
         node = ( { id = { text = 27; }; 
         img = { text = "/upload/iblock/1a1/1a84f.png"; }; 
         name = { text = rtrttrrt; }; price = { text = 0; }; 
         type = { text = 0; }; }, { id = { text = 28; }; 
         img = { text = "e.png"; }; name = { text = gdd; }; 
         price = { text = 0; }; 
         type = { text = 0; }; }, 
        { id = { text = 30; }; 
        img = { text = "9.png"; }; 
        name = { text = gfdghfdh; }; 
        price = { text = 0; }; 
        type = { text = 0; }; }, 
        { id = { text = 29; };
        img = { text = "8.png"; }; 
       name = { text = d; }; 
       price = { text = 0; }; 
       type = { text = 0; }; 
     } ); }; }
```

I'm parsing it and get NSDictionary(called xmlDictionary) like this:

```
result = `{ content = ( { text = "iPhone - shit"; }, { text = "iPad = cool"; } ); date = ( { text = "4 december"; }, { text = "16 december"; } ); title = ( { text = "News about iPhone"; }, { text = "News about iPad"; } ); type = ( { text = "News 1"; }, { text = "News 2"; } ); }; }
```

How can i get attribute of each elements, for example text for title? I'm trying:

```
NSString *str =[[[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"type"] objectForKey:@"title"] stringForKey:@"text"];
```

But it does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: You can get `NSArray *titleArray =[[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"title"] valueForKey:@"text"];`

Comment: NSString *str = [titleArray objectAtIndex:(0 or 1)];

Comment: Yes. Are you surprised? :)

Comment: nought... Its very simple.

Comment: @Erik can you help me again please. NSDicioanry look like this: `result = {
            node = ( 
            { id = { text = 27; }; 
            img = { text = "acc8e84f.png"; };
            name = { text = rtrttrrt; }; 
            price = { text = 0; }; 
            type = { text = 0; }; 
       }
` i'm trying NSArray *titleArray =[[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"node"] objectForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"]; but it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: give the correct structure of your response.

Comment: @Erik updated in question

Answer (score 0):

You can get

```
NSArray *titleArray =[[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"title"] valueForKey:@"text"];
NSString *str = [titleArray objectAtIndex:(0 or 1)];
```

Edit:
Your json structure is not correct in order.Its like as follows,

```
result={
    node=({
        id={
            text=27;
        };img={
            text="acc8e84f.png";
        };name={
            text=rtrttrrt;
        };price={
            text=0;
        };type={
            text=0;
        };
    }
```

So check your response and let me know..

EDIT 2 :

Do like this,

```
NSArray *nameArray = [[[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"node"]  valueForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"];
```